# R Studio - Dataframe with names and years, how to add columns for all previous years?

Tags: r, loops, data-manipulation, dplyr

Going to try my best to explain this well...

Here's a sample dataframe that I'm using:

```
df <- data.frame("name" = c("Ellie", "Ellie", "Ellie", "Ellie", "Nora", "Nora", "Nora", "Jake", "Jake"), 
             "year" = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001),
             "grade" = c("A", "B", "D", "C", "C", "D", "C", "B", "B"))
```

Right now I have a collection of grades of different people over the years (e.g. Ellie's grades from 2000 to 2003). For every row in my dataframe, I want to add columns for how the student did in previous years. So, the row with Ellie 2000 would have NA in all these columns, as there is no data about Ellie pre-2000. The row with Ellie 2001 would have Ellie's 2000 grade in a column titled something like "one year ago", and NAs for the rest. The row with Ellie 2002 would have Ellie's 2001 grade in a column titled "one year ago", her 2000 grade in "two years ago", etc.

Any insight on how to do this? Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the dataframe before for just Ellie (though I'd like to loop through the dataframe and do this for all rows, now just Ellie rows):

```
name . . . year . . . grade

Ellie. . . 2000 . . . A

Ellie. . . 2001 . . . B

Ellie. . . 2002 . . . D 

Ellie. . . 2003 . . . C
```

And the dataframe after manipulating the Ellie rows:

```
name . . . year . . . grade . . . y-1 grade . . . y-2 grade . . . y-3 grade

Ellie. . . 2000 . . . A . . .  . . NA . . . . . . NA . . . . . . . NA

Ellie. . . 2001 . . . B . . .  . . A . . . . . . NA . . . . . . . NA

Ellie. . . 2002 . . . D . . .  . . B . . . . . . A . . . . . . . NA

Ellie. . . 2003 . . . C . . .  . . D . . . . . . B . . . . . . . A
```

The final number of columns (ie. y-what number) would depend on the longest history. So in this case, Ellie has the most entries at up to four years of data, so everyone in the dataset would have columns for y-1, y-2, and y-3.

Comment: Just to be clear can you show your expected output?

Comment: Added that in! Had a bit of trouble with formatting the dataframe but hopefully it's understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, paste0('y', 1:3) := shift(grade, n = 1:3),.(name)]
df
#    name year grade   y1   y2   y3
#1: Ellie 2000     A <NA> <NA> <NA>
#2: Ellie 2001     B    A <NA> <NA>
#3: Ellie 2002     D    B    A <NA>
#4: Ellie 2003     C    D    B    A
#5:  Nora 2002     C <NA> <NA> <NA>
#6:  Nora 2003     D    C <NA> <NA>
#7:  Nora 2004     C    D    C <NA>
#8:  Jake 2000     B <NA> <NA> <NA>
#9:  Jake 2001     B    B <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Super slick! Is there also a way to do this for multiple columns? (if each year had multiple grades for example)

Comment: @Kathy You can do this with `shift` i.e. `nm1 <- vectorofcolumnnames; nm2 <- paste0(rep(nm1, each = 3), 1:3); setDT(df)[, (nm2) := shift(.SD, n = 1:3), .(name), .SDcols = nm1]`

Comment: Thanks very much, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using mostly `tidyverse` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  arrange(name, year) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(p_grade = purrr::map(year, ~rev(grade[.x > year])[1:(n() - 1)])) %>%
  unnest(p_grade) %>%
  group_by(year, grade, .add = TRUE) %>%
  #In dplyr < 1.0.0 use add = TRUE
  #group_by(year, grade, add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('y', row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = p_grade)


#  name   year grade y1    y2    y3   
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 Ellie  2000 A     NA    NA    NA   
#2 Ellie  2001 B     A     NA    NA   
#3 Ellie  2002 D     B     A     NA   
#4 Ellie  2003 C     D     B     A    
#5 Jake   2000 B     NA    NA    NA   
#6 Jake   2001 B     B     NA    NA   
#7 Nora   2002 C     NA    NA    NA   
#8 Nora   2003 D     C     NA    NA   
#9 Nora   2004 C     D     C     NA
```

Comment: This is amazing, thanks very much! Is there an easy way to apply this to multiple columns? ie. if the original data set had test 1 grade, test 2 grade, test 3 grade, etc. I'd assume repeating the process but changing out the variable name, but just curious if there was an easier way

Comment: You can look into `mutate_at` or `across` in new `dplyr` that can help to apply the same function to multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for the help - any chance you can explain a bit more for this? I looked at those two, but they seem to be more for applying a small contained function - not sure how to do it with multiple different variables and names and steps like this one.

Comment: If you have trouble applying it to your data can you please ask it as a new question with relevant data and expected output same as in this post. In that way, you'll get help faster. This will keep this post limited to one question and will not confuse future readers.